# Filling an 2D array with pseudo-random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to C++ and trying to populate and output a 12x12 array using pseudo-random numbers.

Can anyone see where the code is failing?

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

const int i = 12;
const int j = 12;

int myArray [i] [j] = {0};

void generateArray();

int main()
{
    generateArray();

    return 0;
}

void generateArray()
{

    srand(1234);

    for(int i=0; i < 12; i++);
    {
        for(int j=0; j < 12; j++);
        {
            myArray[i][j]= rand();
        }
    cout << myArray[i][j] << " ";
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Yes. And your compiler is telling you. Listen to it.

Comment: You should say ***how*** your code is failing?  Did it compile? Did it run? What output did you get?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  The code is compiling without any issues (at least that I can *SEE*).  The program is returning "4068".  I'm expecting a 12x12 matrix.

Comment: Then you need to teach your compiler to be more helpful... Look up how to enable the strictest of warnings and conformance settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop should look as below.

```
for(int i=0; i < 12; ++i)
{
    for(int j=0; j < 12; ++j)
    {
        myArray[i][j]= rand();

        cout << myArray[i][j] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: That does the trick.  Thank you.  Also, if it helps others who look at this post in the future, I added the following to ensure that the numbers are properly aligned when the matrix prints: cout << left << setw(7) << myArray[i][j] << " ";

Answer (score 2):

Your for loops have semicolons after their closing parentheses.
This will effectively treat the for loop as an empty body (and just ignore the loop in general).

Remove them and the code should execute.

Comment: Thank you.  I do that and now I see only one row of twelve "0"s.  It looks like it's disregarding the rand() function, as well as rows 2-12.